# Misaligned Container Div-- Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What am I doing wrong again? The Placeholder column should align with the container div but it isn't.  Here's the code

```
<div class="container">
<!--Content Area-->
<div id="content" class="row-fluid">

    <!--Main Content Area-->
    <div class="span6" id="main">
        <h2>PLACEHOLDER</h2>
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Marketing stuff!</h1>
            <br />
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. <br />Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris<br /> condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <br />
            <br />

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Get Started</a>
        </div>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    </div>

    <!--Right Sidebar-->
    <div class="span3" id="right-sidebar">
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that the hero unit has some default padding in bootstrap, were as the h2, would have different padding by default. So the left padding/margin will be different and therefor will not align.

Comment: To double-check (because I don't think you mentioned), which version of Bootstrap are you using? `span` classes have been removed in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: But at least the h2 whould have aligned with the navbar but is is not :( @innerurge1

Comment: If you might make a fiddle for it, I'd be happy to help debug it. @gelolopez

Comment: Here it is @innerurge1 http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/442/

Comment: Well, I added your content area as you have it above to your fiddle, and the placeholder h2 does line up with the container div it is nested in. It does not align with the navigation as the nav is outside of the second container div. http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/446/. The first container is inside of the nav div. If you reverse the order of the nav and it's container, things line up http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/447/. Does that solve your issue? or is it something else? If so, I'll post it as a solution.